# Can MySQL update quantity field automatically?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm creating a website using Laravel and MySQL. I have 2 MySQL tables: *posts* and *comments*. In *comments* table, I used a foreign key named *post_id* to refer to which post a comment belongs to. Now I want to keep track of the quantity of comments that belongs to each post, and I have 2 solutions:

a). Put a *number_of_comments* field in posts table;

b). Use *Select count(*)* to calculate the quantity.

For solution a, I wonder if it is possible for MySQL to automatically update the quantity field in *posts* table each time I create/delete a comment or multiple comments. By saying automatically I mean MySQL would calculate the quantity by itself based on table relationship;

For solution b, I wonder how I can do MySQL *orderBy* instruction, like ordering the post ascendingly/descendingly by the number of its comments.

And which solution is better considering write less code and for better performance?

Forgive me for being a MySQL noobie, any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: Search Triggers on Google

Comment: Yeah, that partially solved my problem for part a, thanks!

Comment: As for part (b), you can join your `posts` table with your `comments` table, and order by `count(comments.id)` for example

Comment: I think I get the idea, thanks a lot for the answer:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using MySQL triggers, Laravel provides a more convenient way(as far as I can tell) to accomplish this: Model Events, which handles events like creating/created, updating/updated, saving/saved, deleting/deleted and restoring/restored. So my Comment model now looks like:

```
class Comment extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'comments';
    // Model boot method, the place to register model event bindings
    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();
        Comment::deleted(function($post) {
            $post = $comment->post;
            $post->num_comments -= 1;
            $post->save();
        });
    }
}
```